# Using Keras with own data

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I'm trying to replace the sample data in this [Keras tutorial](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/imdb_cnn.py) with my own data.

To do this, I replaced the line

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data(num_words=max_features)
```

with

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = split(2255, 2394, 0.70)
```

where `split()` is my own function that returns `(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test)`, where `x_train` and `y_train` are lists of lists and `x_test` and `y_test` are lists. Since I'm doing binary classification, 2255 is the number of data items I have in category 1, 2394 is the number of data items I have in category 2, and 0.70 is the percentage of the data that will be the training data.

When running, I get an error that had to do with indexes:

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: indices[1,359] = 2411 
>   is not in [0, 2394)

The main difference between my `(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test)` and the original is size (since they appear to be in the same form), so it may have to do with some parameters that I need to set manually. I tried setting max_features to 2394, but an InvalidArgumentError was still thrown.

EDIT:

I used lists and numpy arrays, as suggested in the comments. This is a sample of the output for split():

X_train's output

```
[list([227, 2075, 9, 236, 1, 79, 7291, 120, 188, 314, 7291, 208, 192, 474, 225, 429])
 list([418, 2411, 95, 128, 1201, 164, 315, 283, 236, 1867, 1211, 443, 1628, 80, 173, 2, 16, 1])
 ...,
 list([1, 288, 149, 536, 40, 214, 1276, 1, 40, 425, 745, 536, 5, 40, 17, 45, 1366, 1, 13, 49, 70, 443, 451, 462, 604, 29, 1, 134, 3, 40, 214, 1033, 2266, 1234, 3, 296, 40, 1640, 369, 1276, 1758, 1122, 448, 536, 9, 25, 277, 85, 369, 62, 79])]
```

X_test's output

```
[list([1867, 50, 67, 1, 222, 274, 54, 417])
 list([5, 1005, 1, 796, 1, 1, 21, 301, 2, 54, 1, 1, 9, 1005, 8, 113, 1, 8, 478, 28, 14, 827])
 list([511, 44, 57, 11, 1, 37, 224, 713, 94, 167, 186, 5, 73, 58, 549])
 ..., list([1, 45, 1, 9, 14, 238, 100, 84, 19, 46, 2, 24, 46])
 list([2126, 536, 417, 153, 358, 12, 973, 1711, 1, 110, 15, 358, 6, 880, 1, 282, 1, 706])]
```

Y_train's output

```
[1 1 1 ..., 0 0 0]
```

Y_test's output

```
[1 1 1 ..., 0 0 0]
```

Like I said previously, I'm pretty sure it has to do with dimensions (since the error is about indexes). Running the code with my data gives the values

```
x_train shape: (3253, 400)
x_test shape: (1394, 400)
```

I'm not using an even train/test split, so the first values wouldn't be the same, so I'm not really sure what would have to be changed.

EDIT2:

The error is the value of `max_features`. The numbers in the arrays are word frequencies in the IMDB data, so `max_features` is the maximum of all the frequencies (the maximum of all the numbers in the arrays).

Comment: You say that `x_train` is a  list of lists, while `x_test` is a list, but I think they should be the same type.

Comment: @OldGeeksGuide Here's the doc for load_data(), if it helps: https://keras.io/datasets/. (Look under the IMDB dataset.)

Comment: If you run the code, you'll see that x_train and x_test are arrays of lists (i.e. "list of sequences" in the doc you pointed to.  `y_train` and `y_test` are arrays of ints (either 1 or 0).  Size doesn't matter (unlike Godzilla :-) ) but if x_train and x_test are different types as you seem to be saying, that would be a problem.

Comment: What does `split` actually return?  Can you post the source for `split` or at least a sample of the output?

Comment: Please post the complete code you're running when you see the problem.

Comment: You must use numpy arrays, not lists of lists. X_train must have the same dimensions as X_test (except for the first dimension, which is the number os samples). The same goes for y.

Comment: @Daniel I started using numpy arrays with the same error. Of the dimensions for x_train and x_test, the second value is maxlen in the code provided. Would that possibly be what's causing the trouble?

Comment: Are those lists of different lengths? You must have a single numpy array (no lists inside the array, no other numpy arrays inside the array, just one numpy array made of pure numbers). Naturally, that will impose that all samples have the same length. If each sample has different lengths, then you will have to pad them until all of them have the exact same size. Normally people use an "empty word" to fill spaces.